# MAC Convert the key and cert into a PKCS 12 (p12) file (Error in PKS12)

Tags: pkcs#12

I am trying to convert the key and cert into a PKCS 12 file, and I get 'error in PKCS 12' . See below, is there anything obviously wrong here?

OpenSSL> pkcs12 -export -out _GoogleLDAP.pfx -inkey -Google_2025_01_20_36244.key-in _Google_2025_01_36244.crt